# Unable to install TP Link TL-WN823N wireless adapter in Kali Linux

Tags: wireless-networking, kali-linux, linux-device-driver

I have been trying to install TP Link TL-WN823N wireless adapter in Kali Linux VM for the last couple of days and still I'm nowhere.

I have done:

- `apt-get update`,
- `apt-get upgrade`.
- Installed all headers, still its not working. In `dmesg` it shows that one high speed USB device which has the product# & vendor ID with Realtek, but it's still not working.
- I tried to install the driver from TP Link website for Linux, still no go.
- While searching online I found a link to install [the driver for Realtek chipset in Kali](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes); that is not working for me also.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: This adapter uses two different versions of the RTL8192 chipset (CU in v1, EU in v2) but note that the two versions use different drivers (https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/rtl819x) If you are going to use a different driver, make sure to blacklist the included one. Also be aware that this chipset does not support monitor mode, so many of the security tools in Kali will not work, I would really recommend swapping it for a TL-WN722N which uses the Atheros AR9271 chipset.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... So if I replace it with TP-LINK TL-WN722N, i think it should work fine right?

Comment: Yes, it will work out of the box on just about any Linux distro, nothing special to at all... The TL-WN722N (Atheros AR9271 chipset) is probably the most compatible adapter out there with Kali and it's tools like Aircrack for under $50. I just picked one up at a local computer superstore for $15 last week, plugged it in and it took off and worked. It's been supported in most Linux distros since 2010 and kernel v2.6.35, and the firmware is open-source. TBH, there probably isn't a better supported wireless-N chipset for Linux out there.

Comment: Some alternatives would be RAlink RT3070 or RT3570 chipset based dongles if monitor mode (aircrack support) is required, if it isn't and you just normal connectivity Google can be of help, there are lots of inexpensive solutions.

Comment: Tnx for your inputs guys... I bght TP-LINK TL-WN722N and its working fine so far.. :)